# Why is Silhouette coefficient (clustering) called Silhouette? Is there a reason behind this name, Silhouette?

Tags: clustering, terminology

Is there a reason behind this name, Silhouette?

Comment: It's the form of the associated graph that drives this, I imagine. (It's quite hard to think of good names for graphs that are both new (for a different kind of graph) and relatively self-explanatory.)

Comment: [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) defines the *silhouette* of a single value and goes on to say that "Kaufman et al. introduced the term *silhouette coefficient* for the maximum value of the mean $s(i)$over all data of the entire dataset." It looks like [Kaufman & Rousseeuw (1990)](https://doi.org/10.1002%2F9780470316801) might be a good place to look.